# chrome extension close or update tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to code an extension that opens the same page in 10 tabs and then updates those pages in a certain interval. If updating is not possible it should close those tabs and open them again.
Right now I have a javascript running as a background-script

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){

var openTabs = 0;
var tabArray = [];

promise = window.setInterval(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://some.com/url/" });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Is there a way to save the IDs of the tabs I already opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to save the ids of the tabs that you have created/opened.

When you call [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) in the `callback` parameter you have access the `tab` object that is created. You then have access to the tabId and can store it using `localStorage` to keep track of them. Something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('tabIds',JSON.stringify([])) //init the store

chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://some.com/url/" }, function (tab){
  var tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabIds')); 
  tabs.push(tab.id);
  localStorage.setItem('tabIds',JSON.stringify(tabs)); //store array of tabsIds
});
```